# Shopify cart - FrontStore API (cart ID) X ajax API (Token)

Tags: api, shopify

I'm trying manipulate the same cart both from Ajax API (via frontend) and StoreFront API (via backend) but i'm not figuring out if the cart created from one have a correlation ID with another approach.

I know that when i add an item in cart via Ajax API a cookie called "cart" is added with an token that persists my cart, in another hand when i create a cart via StoreFront API i get an cartId (a base64 encoded string) that have an token too but it seems that the tokens are not correlated each other, so someone have any clue if a cart created via ajax API is available for manipulation via StoreFront API?

Comment: Interesting. Why are you doing this? What does one offer you that the other does not?

Comment: I have an product that is injected in client's shopify store and i need manipulate the cart via backend (storeFront API) but the cart is created via ajax API ( client's frontend)

Comment: I would stick with the Ajax API to add a product to cart, but then use an App Proxy to callback for any modifications needed to the product in question. That avoids your issue, and would probably work fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's my plan B but today i have an code snippet that is platform agnostic (work in VTEX, magento etc...) and my business logic relay at backend, i'm trying not stick platform based logic on my frontend embed code (this worked until now) but for shopify it's turning out a challenge...

Comment: Shopify is most definitely not Magento, or any other platform. Making the Proxy angle is no big deal. Can take a few minutes to deploy properly, but of course, you need to wrap it in a nice package to make it palatable to the merchants.